# Deserializing a type moved to another assembly

Tags: serialization

We decided to split an assembly into two assemblies. We did and learned that now we cannot deserialize objects graphs that expect types in the aplit assembly (we still have the types but they, we moved from assembly A to assembly A.A or A.B. 
We use .net binary serialization. Is there a way of opening the serialized stuff?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom serialization binder that your formatter uses. In that class you implement the  assembly and class resolution from the old class/assembly names.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder.aspx